# what's the difference between Class(const Class & c) and Class(Class & c)?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

I want to know the difference between the `Class(const Class & c)` constructor and the `Class(Class & c)` constructor in C++.

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
       cout << "running Class()..." << endl;
    }
    Class(Class& c)
    {
        cout << "running Class(Class& c)..." << endl;
    }
    Class(const Class& c)
    {
        cout << "runing Class(const Class& c)..." << endl;
    }
};
```

`Class` is defined as above.

I know that `Class(const Class& c)` is a copy constructor. It will be called when new Class object is created. For example:

```
Class c;  // output->running Class()...
Class cc(c); // output->runing Class(const Class& c)...
```

Now, I want to know  when the `Class(Class& c)` constructor will be called.

Comment: _I know that `Class(const Class& c)` is a copy constructor._ `Class(Class& c)` is a copy constructor [as well](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#1.sentence-1). Const-reference variant is usually preferred (e.g., since copied object is typically not needed to be modified and non-const reference cannot bind const objects nor rvalues).

Comment: For the record, I did *not* vote to close this question as a duplicate, contrary to what the note at the top of the post is claiming, and I don’t think it’s a duplicate (though it may be sufficient to help clear up OP’s misunderstanding).

Comment: If you wish the change the thing being copied as you copy it (e.g., `have_been_copied = true;`) then you want the one without the `const`

Answer (score 1):

Both are copy constructor.

[class.copy.ctor#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#1.sentence-1)

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]).
>   [ Example: `X​::​X(const X&)` and `X​::​X(X&,int=1)` are copy constructors.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that `Class(const Class& c)` is a copy constructor. It will be called when new Class object is created. For example:
>
> ```
> Class c;  // output->running Class()...
> Class cc(c); // output->runing Class(const Class& c)...
> ```

No. Your code [*actually* outputs](https://godbolt.org/z/TigGp5)

```
running Class()...
running Class(Class& c)...
```

And there you have it: the non-`const` copy constructor is called for non-`const` arguments. That’s all there is to it.